# Any idea what substitution may i use?

Tags: limits

Hi please any idea how can i start or at least what substitution may i use here?
Thanks in advance.
$\lim _{x \rightarrow \frac{\pi}{4}}(\operatorname{ctg} x)^{2 \operatorname{tg} 2 x}
$

Comment: Are you familiar with the trick where you rewrite the function inside the limit (let's say $f(x)$ as $e^{\ln(f(x))}$ and use the continuity of $e^x$ to bring it outside the limit? It works pretty well here.

Comment: Is "tg" tangent and "ctg" cotangent?

Comment: Let $\cot x=1+y,\tan2x=?$

Comment: yes joe, tg is tangent and ctg is cotangent.

Comment: I have found that identity on one of my books but it is without proof so i am not sure that i can use it here, the identity is cotan x - tan x = 2 tan 2x, if that substitution can be done that the limit will be easy and the answer will be 1, but i do not think it is that simple so i am confused!

Comment: Start with $x=y+\frac \pi 4$ and work around $y=0$